# Named VirtualHost in apache overrides every other VirtualHosts

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have defined two VirtualHosts on Apache, and the problem is, one of them overrides the other one. i.e. when I try to reach the second address, the first one shows up.

Here is my first config:

```
ServerName www.example1.com
DocumentRoot /server/sites/example1

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example1.com
    DocumentRoot /server/sites/example1
    ServerAlias example1.com
    <Directory /server/sites/example1/>
      AllowOverride All 
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the second:

```
ServerName www.example2.tv
DocumentRoot /server/sites/tv/public/

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@example2.tv
  DocumentRoot /server/sites/tv/public    
  <Directory /srver/sites/tv/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all 
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I load `www.example2.tv`, it still shows `www.example1.com` content.

example1 is written in PHP and example2 is Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the ServerName directive inside the VirtualHost configuration i.e.:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example2.tv
  ServerAdmin admin@example2.tv
  DocumentRoot /server/sites/tv/public    
  <Directory /server/sites/tv/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all 
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can examine your configured VirtualHosts using apachectl -S - this will print a list of all the configured VirtualHosts and their corresponding config files